# How to parse JSON block in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have some piece of JSON information.
Example:

```
"Items":[{"User":{"Id":"123","name":"abcdef","email":"xy@z.com"},"User":{"Id":"456","name":"def","email":"we@z.com"}}]
```

I want to remove symbols such as '{','"' and '}' and store it in the ArrayList such that each element in the JSON has a separate position in a new ArrayList.
The output i am expecting looks somewhat like this:

```
ArrayList[0][0]:Id
ArrayList[0][1]:123
ArrayList[1][0]:name
ArrayList[1][1]:abcdef
etc.,
```

Sample code:

```
public String[] ParseGetJSON (String str){
    String text = str;
    try{
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(text);
        JSONArray item = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("Items");
        for(int i = 0;i<item.size();i++){
            System.out.println("The "+i+" element of the array"+item.get(i));
        }
```

The Output:

```
The 0 element of the array: {"Id":"123","name":"abcdef","email":"xy@z.com"}
```

Comment: That's not an `ArrayList`, it's a `String` in JSON format.

Comment: Why not just parse this as Json instead of an arraylist?

Comment: i have parsed the JSON and stored it into an ArrayList<String> as i need it for further comparisons in my code.

Comment: Please show us a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the original input and what you're doing to parse it to create your `List`.

Comment: My bad!
i did use JSONArray and JSONObject in order to separate, but i didnt use JSONParser. Can you please give me a sample code on how to work with JSONParser for getting the above desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your original input JSON is nested more deeply than you are parsing.  The output you are seeing when you call `item.get(i)` makes it clear that each element of `item` is also a `JSONObject`, each of which has three fields (`Id`, `name`, `email`).

What you want to do is treat each element as the `JSONObject` it is, and parse it as well:

```
    for(int i = 0;i<item.size();i++) {
        // get the next element as a Object and print it
        System.out.println("The "+i+" element of the array: "+item.get(i));

        // get the next element as a JSONObject
        JSONObject obj = item.getJSONObject(i);
        Iterator<String> itr = obj.keys();
        // print all its keys/value pairs
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = itr.next();
            String value = obj.getString(key);
            System.out.println("key=" + key + ", value=" + value);
            // key=email, value=xy@z.com
            // key=name, value=abcdef
            // key=Id, value=123
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Once you have extracted each key and value, you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: hi @azurefrog, by using the above mentioned method i am able to get key=User and value={"Id":"123","name":"abcdef","email":"xy@z.com"}, but i need to get the id as key and 123 as value.
Can you tell me how to parse into one more level?
Thanks.

Comment: @Harsh123 You can always parse another level deeper.  Instead of pulling the value out with `obj.getString(key)`, just extract the embedded JSON with `obj.getJSONObject(key)`, and then parse *its* keys and values.

Comment: @Harsh123 Keep in mind that for very complicated/highly nested objects you're probably better off using an existing parsing library like jackson or gson instead doing it by hand.